# visual studio code-server not workin with compute engine

Tags: nginx, visual-studio-code, debian, google-compute-engine

I host a web site with Nginx in Debian in google cloud.
when I install code server and i visit: my_ip:8443, chrome replied with: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
when I execute the command code-server:

```
INFO  code-server v1.1156-vsc1.33.1
INFO  Additional documentation: http://github.com/cdr/code-server
INFO  Initializing {"data-dir":"/home/naji/.local/share/code-server","extensions-dir":"/home/naji/.local/share/code-server/extensions","working-dir":"/","log-dir":"/home/naji/.cache/code-server/logs/20190723145420188"}
INFO  Starting webserver... {"host":"0.0.0.0","port":8443}
WARN  No certificate specified. This could be insecure.
WARN  Documentation on securing your setup: https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/master/doc/security/ssl.md
INFO   
INFO  Password: ******************
INFO   
INFO  Started (click the link below to open):
INFO  https://localhost:8443/
INFO   
INFO  Starting shared process [1/5]...
WARN  stderr {"data":"(node:17025) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.\n"}
INFO  Connected to shared process
```

what is the solution ?

Comment: yes, i have the port 8443 open in the firewall rules in GCP

Comment: there is a github link in the message you pasted, it seems that you need to create a SSL certificate and add it
https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/master/doc/security/ssl.md

Comment: BTW I deleted my previous comment, cuz I pasted there the password